# Data frames in R

Tags: python, r, pandas

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html)  has proven very successful as a tool for working with time series data.  For example to perform a 5 minutes mean you can use the `resample` function like this :

```
import pandas as pd
dframe = pd.read_table("test.csv", 
               delimiter=",", index_col=0, parse_dates=True,     date_parser=parse)
## 5  minutes mean
dframe.resample('t', how = 'mean')
## daily mean
ts.resample('D', how='mean')
```

How can I perform this in R ?

Comment: You might attract more help from R folks if you explain (in words) exactly what this Python code does, and what the output is. (Since not everyone who uses R is as familiar with Python as you may be.)

Comment: whoa, this is actually the first time I see someone asks if/how R can do something he knows in `pandas`, usually it's the other way around. I don't know if Wes should be happy or sad... sorry, out of topic :)

Answer (score 3):

In R you can use `xts` package specialised in time series manipulations. For example, you can use the `period.apply` function like this :

```
library(xts)
zoo.data <- zoo(rnorm(31)+10,as.Date(13514:13744,origin="1970-01-01"))
ep <- endpoints(zoo.data,'days')
## daily mean 
period.apply(zoo.data, INDEX=ep, FUN=function(x) mean(x))
```

There some handy wrappers of this function ,

```
apply.daily(x, FUN, ...)
apply.weekly(x, FUN, ...)
apply.monthly(x, FUN, ...)
apply.quarterly(x, FUN, ...)
apply.yearly(x, FUN, ...)
```

Comment: there are also mechanisms for this in `lubridate` but they're not as efficient.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde it is from the `xts` package.

Comment: Since @BoleckInk seems unwilling to clarify his question, and you seem to have deciphered it, would you be willing to edit his Q so that it actually makes some sense...?

Comment: @agstudy The edit seems fine to me. I suggest you remove the original version (it will still be there in the history) so the question contains only your version. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

R has data frames (data.frame) and it can also read csv files. Eg.

```
dframe <- read.csv2("test.csv")
```

For dates, you may need to specify the columns using the colClasses parameter. See `?read.csv2`. For example:

```
dframe <- read.csv2("test.csv", colClasses=c("POSIXct",NA,NA))
```

You should then be able to round the date field using `round` or `trunc`, which will allow you to break up the data into the desired frequencies.

For example,

```
dframe$trunc.times <- trunc(dframe$date.field,1,units='mins');
means <- daply(dframe, 'trunc.times', function(df) { return( mean(df$value) ) });
```

Where `value` is the name of the field that you want to average.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I believe it should do what you want now. Could you check?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I really like a combination of **lubridate** and **zoo** aggregate() for these operations:

```
ts.month.sum <- aggregate(ts.data, month, sum)

ts.daily.mean <- aggregate(ts.data, day, mean)

ts.mins.mean <- aggregate(ts.data, minutes, mean)
```

You can also use the standard time functions yearmon() or yearqtr(), or custom functions for *both* split and apply. This method is as syntactically sweet as that of **pandas**.