# ddply on data.frame with date fields

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data.frame which consists of products and different stages of development per project. The columns are the stages and the rows are the products. It looks like this:

```
PRODUCT_NUM || STAGE_1   || STAGE_2   || STAGE_X  
PRODUCT_1   || 01-MAR-11 || 01-MAR-11 || 05-MAR-11  
PRODUCT_2   || 01-JUN-13 || 03-JUN-11 || 03-JUL-11  
...
```

The values of (`productX`, `stageY`) is the completion date for the product at that stage.

I need a summarized data.frame that has the rows as month / year and the columns as `count(stageY)`.

It would look like this:

```
MONTH/YEAR || COUNT(STAGE_1) || COUNT(STAGE_2) || COUNT(STAGE_X)  
MAR-11     || 1              || 2              || 7  
JUL-13     || 1              || 0              || 5  
JUN-13     || 3              || 1              || 0
```

I've actually got a solution using ddply, but my code similar to as follows:

```
stage1=ddply(subset(dat, !is.na(dat$stage1date)),"STAGE_1_DATE", summarize,
MONTH=max(format(STAGE_1_DATE, "%m")),
YEAR=max(format(STAGE_1_DATE, "%Y")),
COUNT=length(STAGE_1_DATE)
)

stage1=ddply(posted, c("YEAR","MONTH"), summarize, STAGE1=sum(COUNT))

stage2=ddply(subset(dat, !is.na(dat$stage2date)),"STAGE_2_DATE", summarize,
MONTH=max(format(STAGE_2_DATE, "%m")),
YEAR=max(format(STAGE_2_DATE, "%Y")),
COUNT=length(STAGE_2_DATE)
)

stage2=ddply(posted, c("YEAR","MONTH"), summarize, STAGE2=sum(COUNT))

stageX=ddply(subset(dat, !is.na(dat$stagexdate)),"STAGE_X_DATE", summarize,
MONTH=max(format(STAGE_X_DATE, "%m")),
YEAR=max(format(STAGE_X_DATE, "%Y")),
COUNT=length(STAGE_X_DATE)
)

stageX=ddply(posted, c("YEAR","MONTH"), summarize, STAGEX=sum(COUNT))

total=merge(stage1, merge( stage2, stageX, by(c("YEAR","MONTH"))), 
            by=c("YEAR","MONTH"))
```

First I aggregate over the days for each stage, then aggregate over months for each stage, then finally I merge all the stages together into one data.frame.

I'm hoping to do this in one shot.

Even better would be to have a function such as function(df,col, func=length) which would spit out the month/year and aggregate numbers for a stage and then I could call this function depending on the number of stages I want to look at.

I've already looked at the following post, but have not been able to implement it for my case.

[R: ddply function applied to certain months obtained from date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110110/r-ddply-function-applied-to-certain-months-obtained-from-date-field)

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave an example of the dataset in the form of an R dataframe and then want the expected outcome dataframe looks like.

Comment: Edited to add code and examples.... Initially wrote it from my phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset is a little short, but I think it could be solved along these lines:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

df = as.data.table(as.matrix(df))

df = melt(df, id.vars = "PRODUCT_NUM")
df$value=ymd(df$value)
df[, value := as.yearmon(value, format = "%d-%b-%Y")]

df2 = df[ , .N, by = list(variable, value)]
df2 = dcast.data.table(df2, value ~ variable, value.var = "N", sum)
df2[is.na(df2)] = 0
df2[order(value), ]
```

Comment: The original data.frame also contains other data types that were irrelevant to the example. I added df = as.data.table(as.matrix(df)) since melt got confused with the dates; I want them all to be factors now.  Then using lubridate we turn them back to dates.  Just added these few lines to be more reproducible.  Thanks for the help! Works great!