# R for loop not working

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R to find the max value of each day for 1 to n days. My issue is there are multiple values in each day. Heres my code. After I run it incorrect number of dimensions.

Any suggestions:

```
 Days <- unique(theData$Date)    #Gets each unique Day
 numDays <- length(Days)          
 Time <- unique(theData$Time)     #Gets each unique time
 numTime <- length(Time)
 rowCnt <- 1


 for (i in 1:numDays)  #Do something for each individual day. In this case find max
    {

         temp <- which(theData[i]$Date == numDays[i])
         temp <- theData[[i]][temp,]
         High[rowCnt, (i-2)+2] <- max(temp$High)  #indexing for when I print to CSV
         rowCnt <- rowCnt + 1 
     }
```

Heres what it should come out to: Except 1 to n days and times.

```
Day       Time       Value 
 20130310 09:30:00    5   
20130310  09:31:00    1 
20130310   09:32:00    2
20130310    09:33:00    3
20130311   09:30:00    12
20130311   09:31:00    0
20130311   09:32:00    1
20130311   09:33:00    5
so this should return:

day time value
20130310   09:33:00    3
20130311   09:30:00   12
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: that should be 5 and not 3

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution using plyr package

```
mydata<-structure(list(Day = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("", "x", "y"), class = "factor"), Value = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 5L), Time = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L)), .Names = c("Day", "Value", "Time"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata,.(Day),summarize,max.value=max(Value))

  Day max.value
1   x         3
2   y        12
```

**Updated1:** If your day is say 10/02/2012 12:00:00 AM, then you need to use:

```
mydata$Day<-with(mydata,as.Date(Day, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
ddply(mydata,.(Day),summarize,max.value=max(Value))
```

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046184/aggregation-by-time-period-in-lubridate/18046378#18046378) for the example.

**Updated2:** as per new data: If your day is like the one you updated, you don't need to do anything. You can just use the code as following:

```
    mydata1<-structure(list(Day = c(20130310L, 20130310L, 20130310L, 20130310L, 
    20130311L, 20130311L, 20130311L, 20130311L), Time = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("9:30:00", "9:31:00", 
    "9:32:00", "9:33:00"), class = "factor"), Value = c(5L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 12L, 0L, 1L, 5L)), .Names = c("Day", "Time", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -8L))



ddply(mydata,.(Day),summarize,Time=Time[which.max(Value)],max.value=max(Value))
       Day    Time max.value
1 20130310 9:30:00         5
2 20130311 9:30:00        12
```

**If you want the time to appear in the output, then just use `Time=Time[which.max(Value)]` which gives the time at the maximum value.**

Comment: I get the same value for each day when I run this. Copied exactly.

Comment: Do I have to write a for loop to plug in each day?

Comment: No, you don't need to use `for loop` when the same can be handled easily by apply function or friends.

Comment: Would you mind explaining that? I'm really new to R. I get results except each day has the same exact result

Comment: This method works with the data you provided - so you'll need to figure out what's different between your example data and whatever data you're using that's causing the problem.

Comment: Have you installed plyr package using install.packages("plyr")?The command is using your dataframe which I called as mydata, and it is finding max value using `max` for each day.

Comment: as @Señor O said your date variable needed to be handled properly before using `ddply`(in your example, this is not the case since you are just saying x, y)

Comment: My date is in YYYYMMDD and my time is military time

Comment: Check your `theData` vs `mydata`

Comment: The question you asked has been answered, so please review your data, find out what the problem is, and post a new question.

Comment: Changed it to my specific data set. Its over 1000 days. Everything works except I get the same number for every day. Its the max value of the whole column which has the values for everyday. – Dennis Mo 2 mins ago edit

Comment: Make sure you post example data that is representative for your real data. @Metrics answer worked for *the data you provided*

Answer (score 1):

This is a base function approach:

```
> do.call( rbind, lapply(split(dfrm, dfrm$Day), 
                         function (df) df[ which.max(df$Value), ] ) )
              Day     Time Value
20130310 20130310 09:30:00     5
20130311 20130311 09:30:00    12
```

To explain what's happening it's good to learn to read R functions from the inside out (since they are often built around each other.) You wanted lines from a dataframe, so you would either need to build a numeric or logical vector that spanned the number of rows, .... or you can take the route I did and break the problem up by `Day`. That's what `split` does with dataframes. Then within each dataframe I applied a function, `which.max` to just a single day's subset of the data. Since I only got the results back from `lapply` as a list of dataframes, I needed to squash them back together, and the typical method for doing so is `do.call(rbind, ...)`.

If I took the other route of making a vector for selection that applied to the whole dataframe I would use `ave`:

```
> dfrm[ with(dfrm, ave(Value, Day, FUN=function(v) v==max(v) ) ) , ]
         Day     Time Value
1   20130310 09:30:00     5
1.1 20130310 09:30:00     5
```

Huh? That's not right... What's the problem?

```
with(dfrm, ave(Value, Day, FUN=function(v) v==max(v) ) )
[1] 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

So despite asking for a logical vector with the "==" function, I got conversion to a numeric vector, something I still don't understand. But converting to logical outside that result I succeed again:

```
> dfrm[ as.logical( with(dfrm, ave(Value, Day, 
                                   FUN=function(v) v==max(v) ) ) ), ]
       Day     Time Value
1 20130310 09:30:00     5
5 20130311 09:30:00    12
```

Also note that the `ave` function (unlike `tapply` or `aggregate`) requires that you offer the function as a named argument with `FUN=function(.)`. That is a common error I make. If you see the "error message  unique() applies only to vectors", it seems out of the blue, but means that `ave` tried to group an argument that it expected to be discrete and you gave it a function.

Answer (score -2):

Unlike other programming languages, in R it is considered good practice to avoid using for loops. Instead try something like:

```
index <- sapply(Days, function(x) {
    which.max(Value)
})
theData[index, c("Day", "Time", "Value")]
```

This means for each value of `Days`, find the maximum value of `Value` and return its index. Then you can select the rows and columns of interest.

I recommend reading the help documentation for  `apply()`, `lapply()`, `sapply()`, `tapply()`, `mapply()` (I'm probably forgetting one of them…) in and the `plyr` package.

Comment: For some reasons I am getting undefined columns selected and when I do index it shows: 
function(x, ...)
{
UseMethod("index")
}
<enviroment:namespace:zoo>

any suggestions?
 Good to know about that for look. thank you

Comment: It'd be better to use `tapply` here: `tapply(Value, Days, which.max)`

Comment: @DennisMo it looks like `index` is defined in the environment as a function from the zoo package. So when you try using it as a variable, R is thinking you are trying to use the function. Just call it `i` or something else.

Comment: @SeñorO you are correct, `tapply` is the better function to use.

Comment: You ought to edit your answer .... at the moment it deserves the -1 vote it got from someone else. The advice to read the docs for the various *apply functions is good but I would add that the `ave` function is also a core function.