# R max value over a series of days

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R to find the max value of each day for 1 to n days. My issue is there are multiple values in each day. Here is my code. After I run it, it shows same answer for each day:

```
20130311   12
20130311   12
```

In the [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137068/r-for-loop-not-working) post, I was suggested to use the following approach

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data,.(Day),summarize,Time=Time[which.max(Value)],max.value=max(Value))
```

My data is as follows:

```
Day           Time              Value 
20130310     09:30:00             5      
20130310     09:31:00             1 
20130310     09:32:00             2
20130310     09:33:00             3
20130311     09:30:00             0
20130311     09:31:00             12
20130311     09:32:00             1
20130311     09:33:00             5
```

The solution for this was provided as:

```
 day         time      value
 20130310    09:30:00    5 
 20130311   09:31:00   12
```

Any suggestions other than using this approach?

Comment: @Metrics, did you downvote for being duplicate?

Comment: @Dennis: Please see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Why not provide example data that reflects your actual issue, i.e. multiple max values per day? You will be more likely to receive helpful answers ;)

Comment: The question has been edited to reflect the earlier question and solution.

Comment: @Metrics, in the comment to your answer, there is the following comment:  _<<The question you asked has been answered, so please review your data, find out what the problem is, and post a new question>>_  We cannot fault a person who is new to SO for following the advice received as far as customs and norms.

Comment: Yes @Ricardo, you are right. But, the new data has also been updated in the earlier question (after that comment) and the solution (using plyr) has been also provided for that.

Comment: exactly, and this question is simply saying, "hey, I still cant figure it out".  No reason for the down vote ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use data.table:

```
DT[, max(Value), by=Date]
#        Date V1
# 1: 20130310  5
# 2: 20130311 12
```

Where,

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table( theData )
```