# R: how to get frequency count by each date and hour

Tags: r, frequency-distribution

I have a dataframe with four variables: "Period", "cell_id", "daterank", and "timerank".
I would like to get a frequency of the cell id's (there are 115 unique levels (or cell_id's)) for each date and each hour by individual Period.
"Period" is a numeric identifier for an individual (5 individuals)
"daterank" has values 0-29 
"timerank" has values 1-24
"cell_id" are numeric identifiers for cells within a spatial grid (on a map). Example values are 101,102,103,104,105,201..205,2401..2405.

The only way I can figure how to do it so far is:

```
####get data by period######2051, 2483, 2507, 2627, 2723###
##tag2051##
tag2051 = subset(fr10000, Period=="2051") ###where fr10000 is the object
head(tag2051)
(d11 = subset(tag2051, daterank=="11")) 
###here, I have to go through each daterank and
timerank combination = wate of time!!
t11h2= subset(d11, timerank=="2")
t11h2
frqt11h2= table(t11h2$cell_id)
cbind(frqt11h2)
```

Is there a way I can get the frequency of "cell_id" for each "daterank" and each "timerank" by "Period" without having to keep changing 
the daterank and timerank value input manually?

Comment: Check the `plyr` package - it is designed exactly for this sort of task

Comment: have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137896/r-max-value-over-a-series-of-days?noredirect=1#comment26564547_18137896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
with( dat, table(cell_id, daterank, timerank, Period))
```

If you wanted to only get the 4 items in your comments:
2051, 2483, 2507, 2627, 2723 then just restrict the data elements to them or us an %in% phrase.

Comment: I used both approaches - they both worked. The answer from @Metrics solved my original problem. That being said, this answer also included all the 0's for dates and times that the frequency in a cell was zero - which is what I was hoping to build.

Comment: The other function to consider is `xtabs`. It has a formula interface, so perhaps looking at `xtabs(cell_id ~ daterank+timerank+Period, data=dat)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested (Date and time should be formatted before using the following function, mydata is your data)

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata,.(cell_id,daterank,timerank), transform,freq=length(cell_id))
```