# adding corresponding time stamp to value in R

Tags: r

So I've been trying for a couple days but I can't seem to figure this out. I am trying to print the max value in a column with the corresponding date.

My theData is in the Following format:

```
Date         Time        Value 
20130811     9:30         12
20130811     9:31          0
20130811     9:32          1
20130812     9:30          8
20130812     9:31          99
20130812     9:32          12
```

The following code was suggested to me in an earlier post and works partially:

```
 max <- ddply(theData,.(Date),summarize, High=max(Value))
```

which yields:

```
  Date     Value 
  20130811  12
  20130812  99
```

I need the code to yield:

```
 Date      Time      Value 
 20130811   9:30       12
 20130812   9:31       99
```

Is there a way to do this without using a for loop?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: -1 As far as I can tell, you've asked this question about four times now, and had correct answers each time. As @Metrics points out, this is *exactly* the same answer given previously

Answer (score 2):

I am going to [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137068/r-for-loop-not-working) my answer from the earlier post, which still is valid:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata,.(Date),summarize,Time=Time[which.max(Value)],max.value=max(Value))


          Date Time max.value
1 20130811 9:30        12
2 20130812 9:31        99
```